# Sql developer: How do I open more than one tab on the same table

Tags: sqldeveloper

I can pin a tab and open other table in a different tab but selecting the same table always highlights the pinned tab.  I want to have two different filters on the same table in two different tabs

Comment: are you opening the tables for edit? if so it makes sense that the locks you would impose by opening the table would prevent you from doing it more than once. if you are just running scripts against those tables though, that should not be a problem (though I suppoose your isolation level may play a factor)/

Comment: Can you open the second view *via* SELECT query?